# crud operation using bootstrap with pnp library

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, boot-strap

I was not able perform crud operation in bootstrap form using SP PnP JS library .

Below is the code:

```
public render(): void {
    let cssURL = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss(cssURL);
  
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Sign In </strong></h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row" hidden>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="empID" class="control-label">Enter Employee ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empID" placeholder="Enter ID">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRead">Read Details</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empName">Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empName" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empGender" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empDesignation">Designation</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empDesignation" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empDepartment">Department</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empDepartment" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empLocation">Location</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empLocation" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empEmail" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
            
            <div id="divStatus"></div>
            <div id="spListData"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`;
    this._bindEvents();
  }

  private _bindEvents(): void {
    this.domElement.querySelector('#btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', () => { this.addListItem(); });
  }

  private addListItem(): void {
    var employeeName = document.getElementById("empName")["value"];
    var employeeGender = document.getElementById("empGender")["value"];
    var employeeDesignation = document.getElementById("empDesignation")["value"];
    var employeeDepartment = document.getElementById("empDepartment")["value"];
    var employeeLocation = document.getElementById("empLocation")["value"];
    var employeeEmail = document.getElementById("empEmail")["value"];
  
    pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeDetails").items.add({
      Title: employeeName,
      Gender: employeeGender,
      Designation: employeeDesignation,
      Department: employeeDepartment,
      Location: employeeLocation,
      Email: employeeEmail
    
    }).then(r => {

      alert("success");
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem here exactly? Are you getting any error or what?

Comment: i am not able add the employee details in SharePoint list

Comment: Try adding breakpoint inside `addListItem()` function and check if there is any error in browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the request has this problem.
[image]

You could know how to solve this problem here:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Using-sp-pnp-js-in-SharePoint-Framework

My test code for your reference:

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import {Web } from 'sp-pnp-js'

import styles from './NoframeworkspfxWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'NoframeworkspfxWebPartStrings';
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse, SPHttpClientConfiguration,ISPHttpClientOptions } from '@microsoft/sp-http'; 
export interface INoframeworkspfxWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}
var moment:any = require('moment-timezone');
export default class NoframeworkspfxWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart <INoframeworkspfxWebPartProps> {

  
  public render(): void {
    //let cssURL = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    //SPComponentLoader.loadCss(cssURL);
  
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Sign In </strong></h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row" hidden>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="empID" class="control-label">Enter Employee ID</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empID" placeholder="Enter ID">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRead">Read Details</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empName">Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empName" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empGender" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empDesignation">Designation</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empDesignation" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empDepartment">Department</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empDepartment" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empLocation">Location</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empLocation" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="empEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empEmail" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
            
            <div id="divStatus"></div>
            <div id="spListData"></div>
        </div>
    </div>`;
    this._bindEvents();
  }

  private _bindEvents(): void {
    this.domElement.querySelector('#btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', () => { this.addListItem(); });
  }

  private addListItem(): void {
    var employeeName = document.getElementById("empName")["value"];
    var employeeGender = document.getElementById("empGender")["value"];
    var employeeDesignation = document.getElementById("empDesignation")["value"];
    var employeeDepartment = document.getElementById("empDepartment")["value"];
    var employeeLocation = document.getElementById("empLocation")["value"];
    var employeeEmail = document.getElementById("empEmail")["value"];
    let web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    web.lists.getByTitle("test_test").items.add({
      Title: employeeName,
      // Gender: employeeGender,
      // Designation: employeeDesignation,
      // Department: employeeDepartment,
      // Location: employeeLocation,
      // Email: employeeEmail
    
    }).then(r => {

      alert("success");
    }); 
  }
  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
  return Version.parse('1.0');
}




  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
  return {
    pages: [
      {
        header: {
          description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
        },
        groups: [
          {
            groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
            groupFields: [
              PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
              })
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
}
```

Test result:
[image]